# Mobile Services Help page : custom metho no added

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am creating a Mobile Services backend with a new Controller, which extends ApiController class.

The new methods are not referenced in the help page. Is there anything to do to register the new methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new route was needed to handle the new methods. The route is added in the WebApiConfig class :

```
        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```